# VIM grep used with shellescape(expand("<cWORD")) won't work

Tags: vim, grep

I'm following "Learn vimscript the hard way" from Steve Losh.

I'm in chapter 32 and trying to implement the following grep remap:

```
    :nnoremap <leader>g :exe "grep -R " . shellescape(expand("<cWORD>")) . " ."<cr>
```

The goal is to grep the WORD under the cursor in the current folder.

I'm having a very curious problem with this remap, it works only if I use it in the first word of a line. If I try to place my cursor above any other word in the line it generates a vim E40 error.

If I use the same remap but within a word instead of a WORD, like this:

```
    :nnoremap <leader>g :exe "grep -R " . shellescape(expand("<cword>")) . " ."<cr>
```

It works with no problem in every word of the line!

I'm using VIM 7.4 on windows.
My grepprg is set to the gnu grep for windows.

Thank you for the help.

Comment: Could you add a sample line?

Comment: It is odd to abbreviate "nnoremap" to "remap" since the "no" modifies the "re":  "n-no-re-map" means, roughly, "normal-mode map, with no nested mappings" or "with no remaps".

Comment: Are you sure it is the position in the line that matters, and not the random non-letter characters that get included?  Try replacing ":exe" with ":echo" to see exactly what command vim is trying to execute.

Answer (score 1):

As noticed by benjifisher, if the word under the cursor has special characters they will be interpreted by Vim (e.g.: if your word contains a '%' Vim will replace it by the current file name). To avoid this use `fnameescape`:

```
:nnoremap <leader>g :exe "grep -R " . shellescape(fnameescape(expand("<cWORD>"))) . " ."<cr>
```